# Is there any way to to execute wmic from html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wmic

Im trying to figure out if we can execute a WMIC from html or javascript.

```
wmic code : wmic /node:"server" /output:"C:test2.html" SERVICE where (state=”running”) get Name, Caption, State, ServiceType, StartMode, pathname /FORMAT:"htable.xsl"
```

html code :

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script language="JScript">
        Function cmds1()
        {
            var run=new ActiveXObject('WSCRIPT.Shell').Run("commands to run");

            objShell.ShellExecute("cmd.exe", "", "", "open", 2);
        }
    </script>
        <form name="input" action="test.asp" method="get">Server name <input type="text" name="Server">
    <input id="E1" type="button" value="submit" onClick="cmds1()">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (and hope) that you can't do that on the clients machine. You can take a look here for some general information about calling exes: [What are some methods to link to and run a local .exe file in a local browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687530/what-are-some-methods-to-link-to-and-run-a-local-exe-file-in-a-local-browser)